# Looping over a SplayTreeMap doesn't give values with duplicated keys

Tags: sorting, dictionary, dart, key, splay-tree

I have a `SplayTreeMap` of players with their levels, and I wanna print a ranking of these players based on their level.

When I use `.forEach` to iterate over this `SplayTreeMap`, it ignores the players with the same level (means that while looping over `SplayTreeMap`, it doesn't take into consideration values with duplicated keys).

Here is my code:

```
SplayTreeMap<int, String> map = SplayTreeMap<int, String>();
    map[5] = 'player1';
    map[2] = 'player2';
    map[6] = 'player3';
    map[7] = 'player4';
    map[7] = 'player5';
    map[7] = 'player6';
    map.forEach((level, player) {
      print('$player -> $level');
    });
```

Here is the output of this code:

```
player2 -> 2
player1 -> 5
player3 -> 6
player6 -> 7
```

So I'm asking myself why it doesn't print `player4` and `player5`.

If there is no solution to this, what's the best alternative to `SplayTreeMap`, to have a map, that's sorted based on its keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [`SplayTreeMap`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-collection/SplayTreeMap-class.html) is a type of [`Map`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Map-class.html), and `Map`s cannot have duplicate keys:

> There is a finite number of keys in the map, and each key has exactly one value associated with it.

(There are `Map`-like classes such as `package:quiver`'s [`Multimap`](https://pub.dev/documentation/quiver/latest/quiver.collection/Multimap-class.html), but they cannot derive from `Map` since they must provide a different signature for some methods (e.g. `operator []`).)

If you want a `SplayTreeMap` with multiple values for a single key, then you should store `List`s as the values.  For example:

```dart
import 'dart:collection';

extension SplayTreeMultiMapExtension<K, V> on SplayTreeMap<K, List<V>> {
  void add(K key, V value) {
    (this[key] ??= []).add(value);
  }
}

void main() {
  var map = SplayTreeMap<int, List<String>>();
  map.add(5, 'player1');
  map.add(2, 'player2');
  map.add(6, 'player3');
  map.add(7, 'player4');
  map.add(7, 'player5');
  map.add(7, 'player6');

  map.forEach((level, players) {
    for (var player in players) {
      print('$player -> $level');
    }
  });
}
```

Prints:

```
player2 -> 2
player1 -> 5
player3 -> 6
player4 -> 7
player5 -> 7
player6 -> 7
```

Note that the above implementation allows duplicate players within each level.  If you don't want that, you can use a `Set<String>` instead of a `List<String>`, or you can use a [`SplayTreeSet<String>`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-collection/SplayTreeSet-class.html) if you want the players to be sorted within each level.